# How to get the new content from the file

Tags: java

Scenario:

1.Create fromX.txt and toY.txt file (content has to be appended and will come from another logic)
2.check every second fromX.txt file for new addition if yes write it to toY.txt

how to get the just new content fromX.txt file?

I have tried implementing it by counting number of lines and looking for any change in it.

```
public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    try {
        byte[] c = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        int readChars = 0;
        boolean empty = true;
        while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
            empty = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                if (c[i] == '\n') {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: well - what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have counted the number of line and compared it every second with the file.Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

You implement it like this:

1. Open the using `RandomAccessFile`
2. Seek to where the end-of-file was last time.  (If this is the first time, seek to the start of the file.)
3. Read until you reach the new end-of-file.
4. Record where the end-of-file is.
5. Close the `RandomAccessFile`

Record the position as a byte offset from the start of the file, and use the same value for seeking.

You can modify the above to reuse the `RandomAccessFile` object rather than opening / closing it each time.

---

**UPDATE** - The javadocs for `RandomAccessFile` are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).  Look for the `seek` and `getFilePointer` methods.

Comment: If you can give an example to implement second point, it would be great help